Generate Activity diagram from C++ code in Enterprise Archtitect
I need to do reverse engineering of a C++ code in EA and generate activity diagram out of it.
I checked HSDc plugin but is it showing sequence diagram generation but there's not much information on generating activity diagram.
How can I generate activity diagrams from C++ code?

You can't generate activity diagrams from code in Enterprise Architect.
You could send in a feature request to Sparx, or write a script or add-in yourself.

Makes no sense. It is plain impossible to create an AD from some code. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

I purposely refrained from commenting on the usefulness and/or feasibility of generating an Activity diagram from code. It doesn't really matter that much since this feature doesn't exist anyway.

Well, I was more referring to your suggestion about the feature request ....
